# Get iso8601.time tag from SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the function bellow. I want to add support for iso8601 time format but I just can't get it to work. Since I in php can't do `(string)$tag->iso8601.time`. Is there a way to get the iso8601.time element? The `tag` is a `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
private function _tagToPhpType($tag) {
        /*
         *  <i4> or <int>   four-byte signed integer    -12
         *  <boolean>   0 (false) or 1 (true)   1
         *  <string>    string  hello world
         *  <double>    double-precision signed floating point number   -12.214
         *  <dateTime.iso8601>  date/time   19980717T14:08:55
         *  <base64>    base64-encoded binary   eW91IGNhbid0IHJlYWQgdGhpcyE=
         *       
         *  Source: http://www.xmlrpc.com/spec
         */

        if(!empty($tag->string)) {
            return (string)$tag->string;
        }
        elseif(!empty($tag->int)) {
            return (int)$tag->int;
        }
        elseif(!empty($tag->i4)) {
            return (int)$tag->i4;
        }
        elseif(!empty($tag->boolean)) {
            return (bool)$tag->boolean;
        }
        elseif(!empty($tag->double)) {
            return (double)$tag->double;
        }
        elseif(!empty($tag->base64)) {
            // @todo: Decode BASE64
            return (int)$tag->base64;
        } // @todo: Add iso8601 time type
        else {
            return (string)$tag;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the manual ([SimpleXML basic usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)) and the associated example (#3):

> Accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the apostrophe.

So in your case `$tag->{'dateTime.iso8601'}` will get an `<dateTime.iso8601>` element.

<sup>(Your `iso8601.time` doesn't match the comment in the code, though if you need to get that tag then it should be easy to work out from the answer above.)</sup>